# Merge statement executing unmatch even though it matches

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book]
(
    [PrimaryAuthorId] INT,
    [AssociatedAuthorId] INT,
    [Description] nvarchar(50),
    [FromDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Book_FromDate] DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    [ToDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Book_ToDate] DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([FromDate], [ToDate]),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AuthorsBook] PRIMARY KEY ([PrimaryAuthorId], [AssociatedAuthorId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PrimaryAuthorId_AuthorId] FOREIGN KEY ([PrimaryAuthorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Authors]([AuthorId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AssociateAuthorId_AuthorId] FOREIGN KEY ([AssociatedAuthorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Authors]([AuthorId]),
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.[BookHistory]));
```

I created an spwith a merge statement which updates when combination of <PrimaryAuthorId, AssociatedAuthorId> already exist while it insert when combination doesnt exist. It does this for
2 of the combinations <PrimaryAuthorId, AssociatedAuthorId> and <AssociatedAuthorId, PrimaryAuthorId>

It has this code

```
declare @PrimaryAuthorId INT =16
declare @AssociatedAuthorId INT =45
declare @Description nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @Book TABLE 
(
    [PrimaryAuthorId] INT,
    [AssociatedAuthorId] INT,
    [Description] nvarchar(50),
)

INSERT INTO @Book([PrimaryAuthorId], [AssociatedAuthorId], [Description]) VALUES(@PrimaryAuthorId, @AssociatedAuthorId)

MERGE   [dbo].Book D
USING   (
    SELECT [PrimaryAuthorId]
            ,[AssociatedAuthorId]
            ,[EndDate]
            ,@UpdatedBy
    FROM
            @AuthorAssociation
    ) S
    (
            [PrimaryAuthorId]
            ,[AssociatedAuthorId]
            ,[EndDate]
            ,[UpdatedBy]
    )
ON D.[PrimaryAuthorId] = S.[PrimaryAuthorId] AND D.[AssociatedAuthorId] = S.[AssociatedAuthorId]
WHEN    MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE  SET
        D.[PrimaryAuthorId] = S.[PrimaryAuthorId],
        D.[AssociatedAuthorId] = S.[AssociatedAuthorId],
        D.[EndDate] = S.[EndDate],
        D.[UpdatedBy] = S.[UpdatedBy]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
    (
        [PrimaryAuthorId]
        ,[AssociatedAuthorId]
        ,[StartDate]
        ,[EndDate]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @PrimaryAuthorId
        ,@AssociatedAuthorId
        ,@StartDate
        ,@EndDate
    );

MERGE   [dbo].Book D
USING   (
    SELECT [PrimaryAuthorId]
            ,[AssociatedAuthorId]
            ,[EndDate]
            ,@UpdatedBy
    FROM
            @AuthorAssociation
    ) S
    (
            [PrimaryAuthorId]
            ,[AssociatedAuthorId]
            ,[EndDate]
            ,[UpdatedBy]
    )
ON D.[PrimaryAuthorId] = S.[AssociatedAuthorId] AND D.[AssociatedAuthorId] = S.[PrimaryAuthorId]
WHEN    MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE  SET
        D.[PrimaryAuthorId] = S.[PrimaryAuthorId],
        D.[AssociatedAuthorId] = S.[AssociatedAuthorId],
        D.[EndDate] = S.[EndDate],
        D.[UpdatedBy] = S.[UpdatedBy]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
    (
        [PrimaryAuthorId]
        ,[AssociatedAuthorId]
        ,[StartDate]
        ,[EndDate]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @AssociatedAuthorId
        ,@PrimaryAuthorId
        ,@StartDate
        ,@EndDate
    );
```

It works the first time it executes which inserts 2 records of the combination of the authorids

The problem is when I run the same script again, I expect it to trigger the update as there is a matching  record, but it seems to give me this error on the second merge statement

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint PK_AuthorsBook

Why does it trigger the insert when there is a match?

Comment: It seems odd to update the PrimaryAuthorId and AssociatedAuthorId to the same values you've matched on. You might try removing those columns from the `SET` clause.

Comment: Your code is riddled with errors, making it impossible to debug. Your table has no columns `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `UpdatedBy`, you don't declare corresponding variables either. Once I have removed everything that stops the SQL from running, it works exactly as expected, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3eee3c54dc6d9d68c9bbf149e31f03c Are you able to post some code that compiles and reproduces the issue?